CanaryOnlyError: The experimental feature "experimental.ppr" can only be enabled when using the latest canary version of Next.js
After adding experimental ppr to next config:

`import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
  experimental: {
    ppr: "incremental",
  },
};

export default nextConfig;`

I get this error:
CanaryOnlyError: The experimental feature "experimental.ppr" can only be enabled when using the latest canary version of Next.js.
is it necessary to update next to canary version (unstable)
Experimental PPR cannot be used in stable Next 15 (but mentioned in docs)

run : pnpm i next@canary
I find the response here : https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/issues/892

In one of my projects, I've enabled experimental.ppr in my next.config.ts without using the latest Next.js canary version, for which I faced compatibility issues. Based on my experience, this feature now requires the latest canary release.
To resolve the issue, install the latest next@canary version by running:

npm install next@canary

After upgrading, experimental.ppr should work as expected.
